# Your thoughts on optimizing a video portal in PHP for performance

Tags: php, performance, optimization, pageload, http-request

I hit here for your valuable suggestion on optimizing one of our client’s video portal which is getting built-up in an optimal way.

We have developed the site in core php with mysql and used a few technologies to making it faster. One thing we find difficult is the page load optimisation, mainly we need to decrease the http request particularly on home page. We have many video thumbnails on the home page in different jquery scrolls.  We are planning to load only the initial set of images first on page load and the remaining on user requests (like clicking in nav button for next image to slide in). But this will only add a small part in optimization. We need to optimize the inner pages too in one way ot another.

Our http request count is 135+ on home page and when I checked in youtube it is showing only 27 request when it doesn’t seems to be low on resources. Do you guys have any idea that how youtube is having that too low.

We uses spirits for images, but that won’t work for dynamic images / video thumbnails. Do you have any idea how to combine the http request for resources into one. I have heard that those industrial giants are using some tactics / technologies for accomplishing that.

Kindly give your ideas and share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you already combining CSS and JS files ?
- Are you minifying them?
- Are you compressing images as best as possible? (plain colors = gif,
  png8...)
- Have you checked your database query performance?

You could also try to make use of cache systems for some content and avoid unnecessary calls to the database. Which is always going to be beneficial.

In case of using jQuery, it is recommended to load it directly from Google libraries because most users would have the files already cached. Anyway, there are some people against this practice too...

About the combination and minification of JS and CSS files, it will also be faster if it is done in the development environment and uploaded "ready to use" to the server rather than letting the optimization task to the server.